# Java net4j newEmbeddedDatabase failure

Tags: java, neo4j, creation

I have such code:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.Index;

public class Model
{
    private static GraphDatabaseService GraphDb_;
    private static Boolean Init_ = false;
    private static Index<Node> NodeIndex_;

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        Parent, Child
    }

    public Model()
    {

    }

    public static void init(String path)
    {
        if ( Init_ == false )
            GraphDb_ = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( path );

        NodeIndex_ = GraphDb_.index().forNodes( "nodes" );
        Init_ = true;
    }
```

After trying to call Model.init("./database/"), i get for the string "GraphDb_ = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( path )":

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1124)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putAll(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1162)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.<init>(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:218)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
    at neosample.Model.init(Model.java:55)
```

This appeares before application starts.
Neo4J 1.9.2, Java 1.7.0

Comment: Which version of Neo4j is this?

Comment: Neo4J 1.9.2, Java 1.7.0

Comment: Can you try to use an absolute path and see if it goes away? Also what JDK are you using? Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: Are you running Init multiple times?

Comment: I'm using oracle jdk and oracle jre. No, static init is running one time from code. I deleted static for init method, made instance of model class and ran init and problem dissapeared, but i didn't understand exactly, what was the trouble.